# How can I update to Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: upgrade, updates

Today is the release of Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo). And I can't update to this version.

And also I selected ‘Notify me of a new Ubuntu version’ and changed it to ‘For any new version' on the Updates tab on Software & Update, but it's still not working. In addition, in the terminal, I've written:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -c
```

And output was:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Follow the steps in [this reference](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-21-04)

Comment: Use `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`  ... the upgrade to 21.04 is still "development" (-d), normally until first point-release (21.04,01 in this case) is released.

Comment: @SorenA 21.04 is a standard release, no point releases (for LTS releases they exist, and upgrade opens **after** the .2, but this isn't a LTS).  There was a 17.10.1 but that was because of a serious issue that required re-spinning of ISOs and isn't a standard case...

Comment: I DO NOT RECOMMEND IT! But you do you, I guess...

Answer (score 53):

The [release of the ISO has only just occurred](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/04/22/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-released/); the update from prior releases doesn't get opened until a decision is made on the *stability* of the new release (*watching bug reports* etc) & a decision is made to *turn the taps* (where people are offered the upgrade).  I'd recommend being patient and waiting until you're offered the upgrade.

You can use `-d` to force... but refer to the [Ubuntu 21.04 Release Notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-notes/19221) where you'll note

> Upgrades from Ubuntu 20.10 to Ubuntu 21.04 are not enabled as it is possible for some systems to end up in an unbootable state if they use EFI version 1.10 - bug [1925010](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shim/+bug/1925010). Release upgrades will be enabled once an updated version of shim is available which is compatible with EFI version 1.10.

Comment: The bug #1925010 is for Macbooks, I guess if you are using compatible EFI there's no problem to use `sudo update-manager -d`

Comment: @Smeterlink Someone there said their Thinkpad was affected as well

Comment: Easiest way to check if one is using EFI (and which version)?

Comment: I would recommend waiting until it's opened officially...  I don't know how to check EFI easily, but I'd look for clues in your machine's uEFI setup (BIOS), then maybe look in `efibootmgr` or use `inxi` (`dmidecode`) (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/man1/inxi.1.html but as it warns (inxi man page) some hardware may not give accurate responses, I'd look for confirmation before I trusted it. Again I'd suggest waiting.

Comment: Yeah, that's my also my strategy (waiting) if I dont have any safety about upgrading. I read that this shouldn't affect modern systems, though..

Comment: If I use "do-release-upgrade  -d" will that change my PPAs to developer channels permanently? Or will it just force the upgrade for this release?

Comment: @IsaacD.Cohen by default `do-release-upgrade` will disable PPA or 3rd party sources. For a clean upgrade it's best to remove all 3rd party packages (ie. `ppa-purge`), perform the upgrade, then after reboot re-add any 3rd party sources if required; as 3rd party packages are the most common reason for issues during the *release-upgrade* process

Comment: As for the upgrade being offered (briefly) then withdrawn again... please see my answer on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338429/ubuntu-21-04-update-available-then-disappears  (ie. issues with other EFI versions etc)