# Ubuntu version update

Tags: package-management, updates, 20.10, versions

Hi I try to update Ubuntu 20.10 to 21.04 but they showing up to date
[image]

[image]

Please help me regrading this,
Thank you.

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text, all text belongs in the question. The problem is simple the update of the feature that would tell you there is a new version has not been updated yet. It will come.

Comment: sudo do-release-upgrade ?

Comment: archisman panigrahi : yup

Answer (score 0):

Since we are after 22nd April you should do the following to upgrade 20.10 to 21.04

Open Software & Update. Go to the Updates tab. Select ‘Notify me of a new Ubuntu version’ and change it to ‘For any new version’. This will tell the package manager to look for the Ubuntu 21.04 release details.

Open a terminal and type the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Once both the commands are complete, open the ‘Software Updates’. And you will see a prompt to Upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04.

Now click on the Upgrade button and follow the on-screen instructions. The upgrade process takes time, so be patient and wait until it finishes. Make sure you have stable internet connectivity for the entire upgrade process.

Alternatively, you can also run the below command to force the upgrade process.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -c
```

[reference](https://www.debugpoint.com/2021/04/upgrade-ubuntu-21-04-from-ubuntu-20-10/)

Comment: I've got this same problem too. Unfortunately, your answer didn't help. It still says all packages are up to date.

Comment: @k314159 Did you first change the settings in `Software & Updates`

Comment: Yes, I did. But then I've read https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333226/how-can-i-update-to-ubuntu-21-04 which seems quite a plausible explanation, so I'll wait a little longer for the upgrade to appear.

Comment: K314159: update-manager -d  try this