# Upgrade Kubuntu 20.04 to latest release (21.04), instead of next release (20.10)

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, kubuntu, 21.04

I want to upgrade from Kubuntu 20.04 to 21.04.

I have changed `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` so that `Prompt=normal`.

Running `pkexec do-release-upgrade -m desktop -f DistUpgradeViewKDE` I get the option to upgrade to 21.10.

[image]

Also,

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop
[sudo] password for cip: 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                                                                                                                    
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1 340 kB]                                                                                                                                           
Fetched 1 341 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                          
authenticate 'groovy.tar.gz' against 'groovy.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'groovy.tar.gz'
```

I guess that should say `hirsute` instead of `groovy`.

---

How to upgrade to latest 21.04 directly?

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333226/how-can-i-update-to-ubuntu-21-04/1333229#1333229

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no tested, supported upgrade path from 20.04 to 21.04.

You have three options:

1. Release-upgrade from 20.04 and 20.10, then again from 20.10 to 21.04.
2. Back up your data and clean-install 21.04.
3. Use the Debian `dist-upgrade` method. We do not test that method, nor provide support if you break your system using it, so I'm not going to explain it.

Mark your calendar: 21.04 will live for only 9 months. You are committing to upgrades every 6 months when you migrate to a non-LTS release. Do not miss the upgrade window.

Comment: Yes, this "Debian dist-upgrade method" is actually cool in Ubuntu - and it WILL produce trouble. I did that several times and ALL installations worked after some days of "help".  The less your system is vanilla, the more you will get severe issues. Idea is simple: Just deactivate as much as possible in /etc/apt/sources.list then change the Ubuntu-name (all!) to the desired version. Update, then upgrade .... and knock on wood. After some reboots re-activate the entries in souceslist bit by bit. Yes, I did that and would not recommend it in case you actually depend on this installation. FF!!