# Ubuntu 21.04 update available then disappears

Tags: upgrade, 21.04

Yesterday, May 14th, Ubuntu showed the availability of 21.04 on all my computers. I successfully upgraded a desktop and a server. For the last computer planned to upgrade today the option disappeared. It showed the availability of 21.04 yesterday but not today. Tried everything, `update` - `upgrade` - `do-release-upgrade` and `dist-upgrade`.  nothing.. Did Canoncial pull back the 21.04 release again ?

In the updater the setting was "for any new version" , but found out that in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` it was set to 'lts'. Weird, because I never changed that. Changed it to 'normal' Still not working...

Comment: I don't see it in https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release (which is why you box doesn't)...   but I've not heard anything sorry.   I do see it in https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development so `-d` will still work..

Comment: How long ago did you change the `release-upgrades` file? I think the actual check is performed by apport. You could try running `/etc/cron.daily/apport` to see if it updates.

Comment: The same happened to me. Checked yesterday (May, 14th), the upgrade was available. I hesitated and checked again today, and it's not  shown anymore. Weird.

Comment: Unusual maybe, I don't see it as weird. I've not been watching release discussions, or release-upgrader bugs filed, but I'm betting a number of 20.10->21.04 bugs were being reported b/c of a condition that can be fixed; so it was disabled until that issue is resolved then it'll be re-opened.. but this is all guess. There will be a reason if for the 'delay' (and/or change).  Groovy still has a couple of months of support left so I'd not worry.

Comment: May 16th sudo  /etc/cron.daily/apport does not solve it. Isee it with -d but don't prefer the -d developer option as would prefer for normal upgrade. and 21.04 was said to be formally been released.  My MB does not use UEFI, it's an older MB but works fine. wondering if Ubuntu had any dependencies to show the upgrade or not.  It seems not an isolated case. (@Mrokki  twice weird :-)). if it's not in the release log, why did it show up two days ago ?  do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release No new release found.

Comment: Formal release refers to the ISO release only.   Upgrades are documented as being opened **after** the actual release, eg. on 20.04 or a LTS release, upgrades occur only **after** the release of the 20.04.1 ISO, and that can be days-weeks after the actual ISO release. We're still only barely weeks after 21.04 ISO, and as documented there have been issues with *britney* or the build infrastructure that has meant a backlog & delays on fixes hotting main repositories...

Comment: How does that explain on one day it shows the update message to upgrade to 21.04 and the next day it is gone on the same machine while another PC also got the message and upgraded normally ? How does that explain other people do see this option ? upgrade steps here https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-to-21-04. I don't recall this kind of situation with other releases and the UEFI issues were fixed IMHO ans I have upgraded this machine for 10 years every 6 months.

Comment: The original shim bug (documented in the release notes as the reason upgrade was first disabled) has been fixed, so the upgrade was turned on... then various users upgrading were filing bugs reporting failure to boot.. another shim bug problem was detected & thus the upgrade tap was turned off again (to prevent more users upgrading & failing to boot...).  Decisions are made based on users experiences (& bug reports) & the moment a pattern emerges that can be easily fixed (delay upgrade) - it was enacted & upgrades disabled again (offer disappeared).. No one currently sees the option to upgrade

Comment: Thanks, is there a place where the "switch" status can be seen ?

Comment: This is the file your machine checks to see if an upgrade is available (https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release); or if you attempt upgrade with `-d` option it looks instead at this file (https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development)  .... The Ubuntu Release Team control what appears in these files   (FYI: It's again SHIM issues impacting other versions & makes... though that's just one issue being watched & part of the decision)

Comment: Ok. thanks.  So it was turn on, then off, then on and then off again. CLOSED

Comment: 5/20 footnote. Was thinking about 21,05/21.11 .Found this. First ASK post and this is on the "tele". ha ha :-) There is one key take away though ... communication to users.they could have make a post on the canonical website. Not it's the end of the world, 20.10 is fine. But though. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hb2xeh936u8  BTW still not fixed https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/04/why-you-cant-upgrade-to-ubuntu-21-04-for-now  and this  is valid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2y2CJndyFOw and this is not https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/05/upgrade-to-ubuntu-21-04-from-20-10 Yup OMG! Ubuntu

Comment: June 2nd. Still no prompt for upgrade. Can't find anyone else reporting this or any futher information.

Comment: Would it mean 21.04 is to be skipped. There are several references of people with issues with Wayland . Canoncial rather not taking the risk and wait the upgrade  out to 21.10 ? there are more and more post advising agaist upgrading and certainly not because of the EFI issue . https://averagelinuxuser.com/ubuntu-21-04-review/  https://fostips.com/switch-back-xorg-ubuntu-21-04/   https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/nm20o8/why_is_my_terminal_showing_no_new_release_found/ "This is because Ubuntu has stopped offering the upgrade path, there were too many install failures" Any reference?

Comment: @Debugging  The upgrade will open when its considered safe and users will be offered the move (unless they've instructed their machine not to offer upgrades any longer) as there is still support life left in *groovy*.

Comment: June 3rd. -tried to update every day w//o the prompt. On 6/3 finally the upgrade prompt showed. The upgrade crashed at updating pixman givng a bit of anxiety for needing a fresh install, After reboot fortunately everything seems ok and this 12 yo machine runs Wayland and Ubuntu 21.06 :-). Now perhaps it's waiting for nVIDIA to support Wayland..

Answer (score 5):

[Formal release](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/04/22/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-released/) refers to the ISO release only. Upgrades are documented as being opened **after** the actual release, eg. on 20.04 or a LTS release, upgrades occur only **after** the release of the 20.04.1 ISO, and that can be days-weeks after the actual ISO release. We're still only barely weeks after 21.04 ISO, and as documented there have been issues with *britney* or the build infrastructure that has meant a backlog & delays on fixes hotting main repositories..

> Upgrades from Ubuntu 20.10 to Ubuntu 21.04 are not enabled as it is
> possible for some systems to end up in an unbootable state if they use
> EFI version 1.10 - bug 1925010. Release upgrades will be enabled once
> an updated version of shim is available which is compatible with EFI
> version 1.10.

The original [shim bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shim/+bug/1925010) (documented in the [release notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-notes/19221) as the reason upgrade was first disabled) has been fixed, so the upgrade was turned on... then various users upgrading were filing bugs reporting failure to boot.. another shim problem was detected & thus the upgrade *tap* was turned off again (*to prevent more users upgrading & failing to boot...*).

Decisions are made based on users experiences (& bug reports) & the moment a pattern emerges that can be easily fixed (*delay upgrade until fixed*) - it was enacted & upgrades disabled again (*offer disappeared*).. No one currently sees the option to upgrade

This is the file your machine checks to see if an upgrade is available

- https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release

or if you attempt upgrade with `-d` option it looks instead at this file

- (https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development

The **Ubuntu Release Team** control what appears in these files

FYI: It's again SHIM issues impacting other [versions & makes](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1928434)... though that's just one issue being watched & part of the decision.  This answer is based on discussions in #ubuntu-release in IRC

Comment: Look at https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/ to see date/times of last change..

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comment done by guiverc I tried "sudo update-manager -d", and that did find the upgrade. Although then the updater tells me that this is still a development release, which seems weird to me.

Answer (score 1):

The 21.04 upgrade became available again through the regular means of dist upgrades (software updater or sudo do-release-upgrade without the -d flag).