# Upgrade from 20.10 to 21.04

Tags: upgrade

This should be simple, but why can't I upgrade to v21?

```
a@sj:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy

a@sj:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

a@sj:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

a@sj:~$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I suppose that 21.04 LTS has not been released, but I set "any version" in the Update Manager and it is not giving me the option:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.

$ tail -n 1 /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
Prompt=normal
```

Comment: Are you using the desktop or the server version of Ubuntu. If desktop, have you tried the `software updater` tool? The correct last command you should have used is   `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: Yes, it is the Desktop version. I run the command while you wrote this, see update in my question

Comment: 21.04 is not a LTS version. LTS come out in April of every even years, So after 20.04, the next LTS will be 22.04.

Comment: I upgraded to v21 today following this steps https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-20-04-20-10-to-21-04

Comment: Likely useful - please scan my answer on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338429/ubuntu-21-04-update-available-then-disappears

Comment: With your help I think I was missing the `-d` option. I will wait to see if everything was correct and publish the steps just in case someone is in the same situation. Great community!

Comment: The release notes tell you how, so just read them.. You can also read other answers here, eg. an earlier answer of mine on 20.10->21.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333226/how-can-i-update-to-ubuntu-21-04 mentions `-d` which is required because it's not yet deemed safe (ie. you may end up with a box that doesn't boot... ; the `-d` means you accept that risk & are willing to use *development* grade software)

Comment: Yes, that answer the question too, thanks. I will not publish the steps because they can be found in the given URLs, and I also bricked the machine with the update....