# Upgrade 20.10 to 21.04 availability

Tags: 21.04

I am using 20.10 and a few days ago I got a message on my update-manager that asked if I wanted the upgrade to 21.04. As I didn't have time then I clicked "remind me again later". Since then offer hasn't reappeared. Has the 20.10 -21.04 upgrade been put on hold?

Edit: There are reports on the internet of a "a broken shim" which is causing some users not to be able to boot their machine after an upgrade from 20.10 to 21.04. I am basically asking if Canonical have put the upgrade on hold and that is why it no longer appears in the update-manager, which is the way I have upgraded for years now.

Edit 2: Following N0rbert's link below I tried starting the update-manager with

> update-manager -d

and then I do get the offer to upgrade! But is it safe? I have a Clonezilla backup of my machine , and so I might try it when I get time.

Edit 3: the "duplicate" doesn't answer the question I asked. That was the reason for the two edits above. Only by calling the -d (development) option do I get the option to upgrade. Does this mean there is a problem with the supported version of the upgrade?

Edit 4: I decided to bite the bullet and try the development version of 21.04. Before the upgrade I got this message

> Welcome to the Ubuntu 'Hirsute Hippo' development release
>
> This release is still in development. An upgrade to it is not
> recommended on production machines at this time. In particular, if
> your machine uses an early implementation of EFI it may end up in an
> unbootable state which would require manual recovery. Upgrades will be
> recommended when a new version of shim is available.
>
> Thanks for your interest in this development release of Ubuntu. The
> Ubuntu developers are moving very quickly to bring you the absolute
> latest and greatest software the Open Source Community has to offer.
> This development release brings you a taste of the newest features for
> the next version of Ubuntu.

Let's see what happens.

Well the upgrade seems to have worked. Feel free to remove this question, but maybe wait until the supported upgrade is available.

Comment: See the 21.04 Release Notes. Specifically, look for the notes about broken shim.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update to Ubuntu 21.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333226/how-can-i-update-to-ubuntu-21-04)

Comment: The upgrade issue related to the shim was fixed & is not a concern any more, thus the upgrade path was opened... however other bugs appeared, which has caused the upgrade path to be re-closed until other (newer) issues are fixed..   There are reasons for decisions, so unless it's absolutely critical to upgrade now - you're safest only upgrading when you're offered the upgrade... (I'm basing this on discussions in #ubuntu-release on IRC)

Comment: Please do not close this question. I can confirm that this is still an issue. I have not been offered an upgrade and `do-release-upgrade` prints "No new release found." I am not comfortable upgrading to a development version of hirsute as some have suggested (`update-manager -dc`) because the installer still warns that doing so is "not recommended on production machines at this time."